# How to save image name in mysql database and then upload the image to the wamp server in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am working on a project which has a desktop application and website and I created a website using PHP and MySQL and now I'm working on the desktop application but I want it to save the image using C# into MySQL database and the image column type is varchar, so I need to save the image name in the image column and then upload the image to the server.
Thanks.

```
class Hotel : helpers.Ioperation
    {
        #region Properties
          private int ID = 0;
          public String name = String.Empty;
          public String logo = String.Empty;
          public String background = String.Empty;
          public int established = 0;
          public String email = String.Empty;
          public String phone = String.Empty;
          public int status = 1;
        #endregion

        #region Helper Classe Objects
          private Database con = null;
        #endregion

        #region Constructore
          Hotel(String name,String logo, String background, int established,String email,String phone) 
          {
              this.name = name;
              this.logo = logo;
              this.background = background;
              this.established = established;
              this.email = email;
              this.phone = phone;
          }
        #endregion

        public int save()
        {
             this.con = new Database();
            int res = this.con.save("insert query",params)
            return res;
        }

        public List<object> retrive()
        {
            this.con = new Database();
            return null;
        }
    }

Database Class

 class Database
    {
        #region Properties

        public MysqlConnection con;
        private MysqlCommand cmd;
        private string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBC"].ConnectionString;
        #endregion

        #region conestructors
        public Database()
        {
            this.connect();
        }
        #endregion

        #region function to establish connection
        private void connect()
        {
            this.con = new MysqlConnection(this.cs);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Insert Data
        public int insert(String query, SqlParameter[] parameters)
        {
            int value = 0;
            try
            {
                this.con.Open();
                using (cmd = new MysqlCommand(query, this.con))
                {
                    foreach (MysqlParameter param in parameters)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                    }

                    value = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            catch (MysqlException ex)
            {
                MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(null, ex.toString(), "Database Error",System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK,System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            finally
            {
                this.con.Close();
            }

            return value;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Select
        public MysqlDataReader select(string query, SqlParameter[] parameters = null)
        {
            this.con.Open();
            using (cmd = new MysqlCommand(query, this.con))
            {
                if (parameters != null)
                {
                    foreach (MysqlParameter param in parameters)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                    }
                }
                return cmd.ExecuteReader();
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please, show us the code.

Comment: i have added my codes to the question could you please now check it, Thanks

Comment: Your question says "MySQL" but your code says `SqlConnection`, which is for SQL Server. Install https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/ and use `MySqlConnection` instead. See https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/connect-to-mysql/

Comment: Yes I did that now I am using Mysqlconnection instead of sqlconnection

Comment: Please focus on my main problem